# Не установить Gulp 4

Tags: gulp, npm, gulp4

кто знает подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем дело. При попытках установить Gulp 4 я получаю ошибки:

```
C:\Users\Kaly\Desktop\gulp>npm install gulp@next
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for gulp@next
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

Comment: А зачем `@next`? `npm i gulp` и так прекрасно устанавливает версию 4.0.0.

Comment: Я не знала, просто по видео уроку делаю. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, наверно, видеоурок создавался в те времена, когда 4 версия официально еще не вышла.